# How to Mount vbox permanently

Tags: bash, ubuntu-11.10, automount

On my Ubuntu 11.10 machine, I use vbox (which is again an Ubuntu with source code on it). To take a daily update of a code, followed by testing - have to mount this box with every restart. Tried to change etc/fstab and also tried to bookmark it but it's not working. Could someone please help about it? Can a bash script be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing `/etc/fstab` as root:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add this line at the end of the file:

```
mySharedFolderNameAsConfiguredInVBox /home/me/mysharedfolder vboxsf defaults 0 0
```

Note that `/home/me/mysharedfolder` must exist (`mkdir /home/me/mysharedfolder`).

Also keep an empty line at the end of `/etc/fstab/` other whise it may not work.

Everything should be working now! ;)

Comment: Well, I apologize for creating confusion here. I don't have a shared folder in Vbox, rather it's an entire vbox that I would like to automount.

Comment: @Fagun What do you mean by a vbox? Is it the virtual machine or a virtual harddrive you want to mount to your vitrual machine?

Comment: It's a virtual machine which I want to mount. Currently I am doing it by executing this command: sshfs <username>@<ipaddress>:/home /media/box, which gets unmounted as soon as system is off

Comment: Then create a new file `/etc/init.d/S99mymount` with the following inside:
`#!/bin/sh
 #place return here in your file
# mounting the vbox:
sshfs <username>@<ipaddress>:/home /media/box &          # <-- Don't forget the "&" otherwise other system stuff won't start until this returns !!!
 #place return here in your file
exit 0 
 #place return here in your file
`
This script will be executed on the startup of your machine automatically.

Comment: If the last comment worked I can correct the answer

Comment: I believe it was a terrible misunderstanding from my side. sshfs mounts file-system as a non-root user,while through script, i was trying to mount as a root-user. I made an entry in autostart as box.desktop and added public key to remote machine's .ssh folder and it's working fine. Thanks a lot for the help again and sorry for the misunderstanding :-)